# What does it mean when Google Maps says "moving"?

Tags: google-maps

I left work like it says , drove to my friends which you can see , but it says I was moving from 8.23 am -2.30 am but that I didn't leave. I don't think I accidentally turned it off when I left that morning. So what does it mean to say moving.

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

From the last point (Harding's) to your current point, it assumes that you were moving, probably because of changes in distance or because of movement.